# vbs changes < to &lt; and my > to &gt; when importing file contents

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have absolutly no idea when it comes to VBScript so I was quite happy when I frankensteined two simple code snippets found online to insert the entire contents of a text file into a XML document.

All works well except my `<` have changed to `&lt;` and my `<` has changed to `&gt;`.

How can I overcome this?

My code:

```vb
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test.txt", ForReading)

strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load("C:\Audits.xml")

Set colNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/TOOLS")

For Each objNode In colNodes
   objNode.text = (strText)
Next

xmlDoc.Save "C:\Audits.xml"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CDATA section allows < and >:

> CDATA sections allow developers to include the markup characters <, >,
>   and & within element content without using character or entity
>   references. Scripts, style sheets, program code, and sample XML code
>   are frequently contained in CDATA sections.

([Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Code:

```
  Dim oXML : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
  Set oXML.documentElement = oXML.createElement("a")
  Dim nd
  Set nd = oXML.createElement("b")
  nd.appendChild oXML.createTextNode("<>")
  oXML.documentElement.appendChild nd
  Set nd = oXML.createElement("c")
  nd.appendChild oXML.createCDATASection("<>")
  oXML.documentElement.appendChild nd
```

output:

```
<a><b>&lt;&gt;</b><c><![CDATA[<>]]></c></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't "overcome" this. `<` and `>` characters **must** be encoded, otherwise there'd be issues with parsing the XML tags (which are demarcated by angular brackets, i.e. `<` and `>` characters).