# Creating CDATA with VBScript XMLDOM

Tags: vbscript, xmldom

I'm trying to create a node in an existing XML document using VBScript. I have created the node but I can't quite understand how to create the CDATA Section to actually use "<" and ">".

The node I'm trying to create looks like:

```
<Notes><![CDATA[ <font color="red"><b>After you have downloaded the application:</b></font><br/>Please download and run this configuration. <a href="Application/Updates/Config.exe">Config.exe</a><br/> ]]></Notes>
```

I'm using Microsoft.XMLDOM so each "<" creates as "&lt" and so on, am I not using createCDATASection properly? I have tried several ways to get the script to stop using "&lt" and "&gt" but I have gotten nowhere.

Using:

```
set cdatatest = objXMLDoc.createCDATASection("<font color=""red""><b>After you have downloaded " & strProductName & _
":</b></font><br/>Please download and run this configuration. <a href=""Application/Updates/" & _
strConfigFile.Name & """>Config.exe</a><br/>")

objNotes.appendChild(cdatatest)
```

Results in:

```
<Notes>&lt;font color="red"&gt;&lt;b&gt;After you have downloaded the application:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Please download and run this configuration. &lt;a href="Application/Updates/Config.exe"&gt;Config.exe&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;</Notes>
```

Comment: How are you serializing the XML (using the `save` method or the `xml` property, or something else like MXXMLWriter, for example)? I just tested this using "Microsoft.XMLDOM" as well as "Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0" and "Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0", and they all produced a CDATA section either using `save` or `xml`.

Comment: Using the code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13808427/603855 and your data produced correct XML.

Comment: OK, you got me!! it was the way I was saving the file. With that being said what is the best way to save the xml with formatting? I was using ( "MSXML2.SAXXMLReader") to convert the stream into something that wouldn't blind me when I tried to look at it.

Comment: The strangest part is Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0, at least, does not mess up the formatting from previous entries.