# Append a CDATA section

Tags: xml, vbscript

Having to do some work in some old VBScript, I need to add a CDATA section to some XML, can someone let me know if this looks right, and how I would go about extracting the text from the CDATA section later.

```vb
Dim xmlobj
Set xmlobj = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
p_conditon = Server.HtmlEncode(condition)
xmlobj.LoadXML "<CONDITION>" & condition & "</CONDITION>"
Set Condition_Node = xmlobj.SelectSingleNode("/node()")
```

Above is the existing code and I am adding the following section

```vb
Dim cdata
Set cdata = xmlobj.CreateCDATASection(REPLACE(condition, "&amp;&amp;", "&&"))
Condition_Node.AppendChild(cdata)
```

The existing code to extract the CONDITION is this, but I need to check if it has a CDATA section and if so, extract the text from it.

```vb
field.SelectSingleNode("CONDITION").text
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I am in the process of trying the append, but I have no idea how to go about retrieving it later, testing is a pain as this is only part of a series of steps to get to this bit of code, so it's long winded, hoping someone can help in the mean time

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part of your question, I steal the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13808427/603855)

```
Dim oXML : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
Set oXML.documentElement = oXML.createElement("a")
Dim nd
Set nd = oXML.createElement("b")
nd.appendChild oXML.createTextNode("<>")
oXML.documentElement.appendChild nd
Set nd = oXML.createElement("c")
nd.appendChild oXML.createCDATASection("<>")
oXML.documentElement.appendChild nd
```

and - for the second part in the comment - I append:

```
WScript.Echo oXML.xml
Set nd = oXML.SelectSingleNode("/a/c").firstChild
WScript.Echo nd.nodeType, nd.text, nd.xml
Set nd = oXML.SelectSingleNode("/a/b").firstChild
WScript.Echo nd.nodeType, nd.text, nd.xml
```

output:

```
<a><b>&lt;&gt;</b><c><![CDATA[<>]]></c></a>

4 <> <![CDATA[<>]]>
3 <> &lt;&gt;
```

See the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247)

```
...
 interface Node {

  // NodeType
  const unsigned short      ELEMENT_NODE                   = 1;
  const unsigned short      ATTRIBUTE_NODE                 = 2;
  const unsigned short      TEXT_NODE                      = 3;
  const unsigned short      CDATA_SECTION_NODE             = 4;
  const unsigned short      ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE          = 5;
...
```

for the numbers.

Comment: That seemed fine for desktop, unfortunately I needed to test this on an iPad app and it seems to be ignoring the CDATA, I read somewhere there is  PCDATA, but I can't work out how I add that to the XML